# check if winform is hidden behind a game running in exclusive full screen mode

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have a layered window/form which I try to always set on top of any other window in the desktop using SetWinPos WinAPI method, I can get over almost any window, only problem is if I have a full screen game on my desktop and then I call SetWinPos to put my form on top of the game, its actually being recognized as the "top window" based on the return value of GetTopWindow WinAPI method, I can even see mouse cursor changed when I hover in some parts of the game screen ( I supposed since the form is actually the "top window") but then I don't really see my form since game is in exclusive full screen mode...

Is there any way to check if my form is hidden behind a game (or perhaps any app which is running in exclusive full screen) or check if a game is actually running in exclusive full screen mode?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure but it sounds like your game is running in DirectX-Fullscreen, which AFAIK isn't exactly the same as win-api full screen. I don't know where but you might be able to check your apps position by also querying directx-api.....as I said..not sure about any of this...